# Is this the correct way to convert Android hex RGB color value to iOS xcode RGB value?

Tags: android, ios

I'm using #ff303030 as the color of Acitonbar in Android and want to add this color to xcode for use in iOS navigation bar.
[RGB vlue enterd in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob1Da.png)
The opacity is set to 100% and the hex RGB value is set to #303030.
But somehow the color of the navigation bar in iOS looks ligter than in Android.
Don't really know why.
(I was using Bar Tint as the attribute to configure the navigation bar color in xcode for iOS)
[Navigation bar attribute in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YHis.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have selected sRGB color profile in colors:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My navigation bar looks a lot darker now.